# How to know which specific toastr was clicked?

Tags: angular, toastr

I have successfully shown toast by ngx-toaster.
By i am showing toaster for various type of notifications as per id and taskcode.

I tried to get tap callback and action callback but did not found anything in return.

```
onNotificationReceived(res) {
        let key;
            switch (key) {
                case 1:
                    showSuccessPopup(res.title,res.body);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
    }

showSuccessPopup(title,body) {
        this.toastr
            .success(title, body, { closeButton: true })
            .onTap.subscribe((action) => console.log(action))
    }
```

Actual Result: Toast shown

Expected: For which id toast was shown

Answer (score 4):

```
onNotificationReceived(res) {
        let key;
            switch (key) {
                case 1:
                    showSuccessPopup(res.title,res.body);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
    }

showSuccessPopup(title,body) {
        const toast = this.toastr
            .success(title, body, { closeButton: true });
        toast.onTap.subscribe((action) => console.log(toast.toastId));
    }
```

You can pass the `toastId` to your callback from the actual ActiveToast instance.

Unfortunately none of the callbacks will return the actual toast object itself!

Answer (score 0):

`this.toastr.success()` shows a toastr notification and returns a `ActiveToast`-Object. And you call `onTap` on that specific toastr. If you want to access the toastr-object in the subscription save it in a variable:

```
const toastr = this.toastr.success(/* ... */);
toastr.onTap.subscribe(action => /* use toastr here */);
/* you can also use toastr here */
```

`toastr` looks like this:

```
export interface ActiveToast {
  /** Your Toast ID. Use this to close it individually */
  toastId: number;
  /** the message of your toast. Stored to prevent duplicates */
  message: string;
  /** a reference to the component see portal.ts */
  portal: ComponentRef<any>;
  /** a reference to your toast */
  toastRef: ToastRef<any>;
  /** triggered when toast is active */
  onShown: Observable<any>;
  /** triggered when toast is destroyed */
  onHidden: Observable<any>;
  /** triggered on toast click */
  onTap: Observable<any>;
  /** available for your use in custom toast */
  onAction: Observable<any>;
}
```

see the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

Comment: what if you get multiple notification at a time? newer notification will change current value...